# how to run and install ubuntu 18.4 on oracle vm

Tags: server

I'm new to Ubuntu and I have this Virtual Machine issue when installing Ubuntu.I have done a huge search to overcome this but I failed.So please help me out. I'm using Oracle VM (Virtual Box) 4.2.14 and I have installed it on Windows 10

[image] (64 bit). Following are the settings. And

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could expand and show the full error and if we could see the setting of the VM. Firstly I would check and make sure virtualization technology is enabled for your CPU in the BIOS. Then I would try running it as an administrator. Next try rebuilding the VM and then I would also try reinstalling VirtualBox. Without more specific details of the error, we really cannot help.

Comment: i am new to it pls can you tell me how to do that

Comment: @worldwideclass firstly, check to see if virtualization is enabled. Open up your task manager and then navigate to the performance tab. Look and see if you see "Virtualization Enabled". If it is not enabled, you will need to enable it. To do so, find the make and model of your PC and simply google "How to enable virtualization for 'Your PC Model Here'". Once that is completed. Retry by rebuilding the VM and then starting it.